# Org IP Addresses

Tags: org, address

Is there a Salesforce site that has the IP range for each Salesforce data center? I am assuming my salesforce instance does not have a static IP address, but am wondering what is the minimum amount of IPs I have to whitelist for my org to interact with my firewall.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

> **What are the Salesforce IP Addresses & Domains to whitelist?**
>
> At Salesforce, trust is our #1 value. We understand that customers
>   need to be confident that they are communicating with Salesforce in a
>   secure environment. IP whitelisting is one of the most effective
>   methods of ensuring this and prevents any internet traffic intended
>   for Salesforce from being hijacked or rerouted to a rogue website. Our
>   complete portfolio of IP addresses and Domains are outlined below for
>   our customers to reference when establishing and maintaining their
>   corporate network and email settings.